# Redirecionamento HTTP e HTTPS com exceção

Tags: htaccess, http, https

Tenho um site em *http* e adicionei um certificado *SSL*. Preciso de um *script* via *htaccess* que redirecione todo o site para *https* (redirecionamento 301), porém uma única página especifica do site precisará ser acessada via *http:*
Exemplo:

https://meusite.com  ***Todas as páginas do site com https***

http://meusite.com/pagina-especifica ***Apenas essa página sem o https***

No caso, essa página poderá até ser acessada via *https*, mas também precisará necessariamente ser acessada via *http* sem redirecionamento.

Tentei esse código, porém dá erro de excesso de redirecionamento. A intensão seria permitir que a página meusite.com/api fosse acessível tanto via http quanto via https sem redirecionamento.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(api) [NC] #permite tanto acesso via https quanto http
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Esse outro código abaixo funcionou perfeitamente para o redirecionamento 301 do site, entretanto não estou conseguindo incluir a exceção para que a página /api seja também acessível sem o https:

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^meusite\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL
# BEGIN WordPress
```

Comment: Olá @Bacco, obrigado por responder. Adicionei o que tenho pronto para ver se auxilia. Basicamente o que preciso é um código padrão de redirecionamento 301 via htaccess de http para https, porém preciso incluir uma regra para que apenas uma única página especifica do meu site seja acessível também via http, sem redirecionar para https.

Comment: Sua lógica tá indo bem, só que não pode redirecionar de novo se já for HTTP só. Talvez fosse melhor juntar os cond num rewriterule só. Só redirecione se for HTTP, **E** se não for **/api**

Comment: Então, seria justamente isse "E se não foi /api" que não estou conseguindo. Sou novato nisso.

Comment: Olha só realmente existe a necessidade de deixa a API sem HTTPS? Essa API vai dar acesso pra quem? Terceiros ou seu próprio sistema?

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente isso resolva. É parecido com a sua primeira versão, mas foi corrigido um `!=` e o `https` no `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api.* [NC] #essa linha é a exceção
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Se o redirect não fosse 301, bastaria omitir da flag `R`:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Veja só um exemplo se a exceção fosse um domínio específico, por exemplo:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC] #exceção pra domain.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Notar que foram tirados os parênteses de algumas situações, pois geralmente só se faz agrupamentos quando vai ser usado aquele pedaço no `RewriteRule`, com os grupos de captura `%1`, `%2` etc.