# Meu site da erro 404 quando uso redirecionamento https

Tags: php, htaccess, https

Meu site da erro 404 quando mudo o htacces para redirecionar http para https, o código que estou usando no htacces:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

estou usando php - Laravel

Comment: E seu site responde normalmente acesando diretamente por HTTPS?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143653/70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes

# WWW Redirect.
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# HTTPS Redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# URL Rewrite
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

**# WWW Redirect** = Força o redirecionamento quando for digitado **WWW**

**# HTTPS Redirect** = Força o redirecionamento para HTTPS

**# URL Rewrite** = Aplica as condições do arquivos, aplicando as regras para arquivos (!-f) e para os diretórios (!-d)

Link da documentação do apache, onde uma explicação mais exemplos das configurações possíveis.

[Documentação Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html)